# How can I prevent football/soccer net theft?

Tags: football, equipment

I work at a primary school and the soccer nets have been stolen. The goal frames are still there, but the nets are gone. Is there a way to replace them so that they won't be stolen again? I thought perhaps making the nets removable? I've seen anti-vandal anti-theft goals online but I'm not sure what makes them so.

Comment: Growing up in the inner city, our public soccer and basketball nets were always made out of chain link for this very reason. Of course, these days we're concerned about things like Tetanus, but there's the tradeoff.

Answer (score 13):

In general, the "anti-vandal" or "anti-theft" refers to the goal frames themselves, rather than the nets; there's very little you can do if someone is actually out to vandalise the net with a big pair of scissors or equivalent. The simplest solution by far is just to put the nets up when you need them - this then just becomes a question of whether it is more cost effective to replace the nets when they are stolen or have your staff time spent putting up and taking down the nets every time they are needed.

Comment: At my high school it would be us the players putting up and taking down the nets. The coach (who typically was a school teacher) would have a key to a locker / shed where they were kept. This was also the case at the club I played for

Answer (score 10):

I can suggest you one of those three solutions:

1. use it without net except during official games, on these occasions you should assemble and dismantle the net with a consequent loss of time
2. add wheels to completely remove the goal frames at the end of matches/trainings
3. use rigid net (it is easy to see it on 3 vs 3 ground, but I do not know if exists for normal goal frames)

Here you can see movable wheels for solution 2

[image: wheels] - [image: wheels]

Answer (score 2):

You should make a net [with thin chains](https://www.google.com/search?q=soccer+chain+net&safe=strict) and have the poles fixed into solid concrete ground or welded to some other metal railing etc.

Comment: -1. Setting goalposts into concrete is a sure way of causing injuries to people and damage to the most commonly ruined area of the field. Any other railings present would be against the laws of football and an enormous additional safety problem regardless.

Comment: @Nij. depends on where you live. Here in NZ they can be set in the ground like that if there is no need to remove them, otherwise they can be lifted into a dedicated metal hole pipe, which is not easy to just remove by anyone

Comment: @Nij same as aqwert says, depends on the locality, if there is too much theft going on, instead of purchasing nets again and again you just fix it up once. 
And as for safety you can simply use rubber pads near dangerous areas.

Comment: Rubber pads on goalposts? Not in any competition I've seen.